# HTML form action relative path wrong

Tags: html, forms

I have a form with a relative path action `action="updateItem/:id"` in the route `/wishlist/admin`. I expected this to post to `/wishlist/admin/updateItem/:id` but it's posting to `/wishlist/updateItem/:id` instead.

Is there any way to make this relative to the current page or should I add `admin/` to the start of the form action?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A relative path replaces everything after the last `/` in the existing path.

Your base URL needs to be `/wishlist/admin/` and not `/wishlist/admin`.

---

I generally recommend using absolute paths to avoid any issues with having two similar URLs like that.